# Validating a X509Chain with a revocation policy set to Online against a CRL that has a Next date set to years back fails because of revocation check

Tags: ssl-certificate, .net-7.0, client-certificates, x509certificate2

I have this Chain validation set up:

```cs
var chain = new X509Chain();
chain.ChainPolicy.TrustMode = X509ChainTrustMode.CustomRootTrust;
chain.ChainPolicy.CustomTrustStore.Add(_options.CA);
chain.ChainPolicy.CustomTrustStore.Add(_options.Intermediate);
```

Where i want to call

`chain.Build(clientCertificate);`

on a client certificate. I need to do this:

`chain.ChainPolicy.RevocationMode = X509RevocationMode.NoCheck;`

To get it to work. I know that the certificates in my custom store is pointing to a valid CRL. I can even download it, but when i download it, I can see that the CRL next date is way in the past (january 2018), which in my mind makes the CRL invalid.

My two questions is:

- When i validate a certificate with `RevocationMode` set to something other than `NoCheck` and the CRL has a `Next date` < `DateTime.UtcNow` (that is: `Next date` is in the past), will it fail the revocation check on that background?
- Does it matter that i use a Custom root store? Or does revocation only work if i use the certificate store in Windows?

I am on `.NET 7` (tried the above on both Windows and Linux).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When i validate a certificate with RevocationMode set to something other than NoCheck and the CRL has a Next date < DateTime.UtcNow (that is: Next date is in the past), will it fail the revocation check on that background?

no. In this case, certificate chaining engine will skip any revocation checking.

> Does it matter that i use a Custom root store? Or does revocation only work if i use the certificate store in Windows?

it doesn't matter as long as custom store is trusted by the chaining engine, which is (based on your code).

Comment: I wrote it a bit cryptic: I want to know if the revocation fails if I set it to Online or Offline, and NOT NoCheck, and the Next date is in the past. Does the chain invalidate the cert just because the CRL is invalid, or doesn't it rely on the Next date? Eight now it fails if I set it to Offline or Online with s CRL that contains s Next date that I'd in the past, but I can't quite figure out if it is because of a invalid CRL.

Comment: You can figure out exact failure reason by examining `chain.ChainElements` collection.

Comment: Aaahh. I didn't notice that it has a `CtlNotTimeValid` status. I will see if this is what I get.

Comment: I can see that i get two status elements in `ChainStatus`: `OfflineRevocation` and `RevocationStatusUnknown`. Which is kind of strange, because the CRL is present in the certificate. I would expect it to be `CtlNotTimeValid`. The CRL is only on the intermediate, and there is no CRL distribution point on the root. Could this be the culprit?

Comment: CTL is a different thing than CRL. When CRL is absent, expired or otherwise is not valid, the function will report revocation offline.